# PHPUnit fails to load files with namespace statement

Tags: php, namespaces, phpunit

When trying to load a source file with an absolute `namespace \Blah;` declaration from PHPUnit, the loading fails:

```
Fatal error: Undefined constant 'Blah' in C:\path\to\file.php on line 3

Call Stack:
...
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching the internet, I found a solution suggested by Eric Hogue on Twitter:
Use a relative namespace declaration, i.e. `namespace \Blah;` becomes

```
namespace Blah;
```

https://twitter.com/JeremyKendall/status/294956904067780610

Comment: PHPUnit 4.8 also needs it to be like that.